# Is it possible to create a HDF5 structure matching the file path on a local pc?

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I am trying to automatically create a HDF5 structure by using the file paths on my local pc. I want to read through the subdirectories and create a HDF5 structure to match, that I can then save files to. Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The HDF5 schema mimics the directory(folder)/file structure of a computer. Groups are used to represent the directory structure and datasets hold the data in the files.  The "challenge" is converting the files into datasets (which are typically homogeneous or heterogeneous arrays). What are the files you want to save?

Comment: The issue I have is not with storing the data in HDF5 dataset. It is creating a script that will replicate the subdirectories of a given path

Comment: There is no need to import the files? You only want to mimic the directory/folder structure?

Comment: Yes, I want to replicate the directory/folder structure and then I will add data to that structure in HDF5

Comment: A few more questions - will the starting directory be the top level (aka root) directory (eg '/')? ? Linux or Windows? If Windows, how do you want to handle the drive letter (eg 'C:')?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by combining `os.walk()` and h5py `create_group()`. The only complications are handling Linux vs Windows (and drive letter on Windows). Another consideration is relative vs absolute path. (I used absolute path, but my example can be modified. (Note: it's a little verbose so you can see what's going on.) Here is the example code (for Windows):

```
with h5py.File('SO_73879694.h5','w') as h5f:
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    for root, dirs, _ in os.walk(cwd, topdown=True):
        print(f'ROOT: {root}')
        # for Windows, modify root: remove drive letter and replace backslashes:
        grp_name = root[2:].replace( '\\', '/')
        print(f'grp_name: {grp_name}\n')
        h5f.create_group(grp_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually quite easy to do using [HDFql](https://www.hdfql.com) in Python. Here is a complete script that does that:

```
# import HDFql module (make sure it can be found by the Python interpreter)
import HDFql

# create and use (i.e. open) an HDF5 file named 'my_file.h5'
HDFql.execute("CREATE AND USE FILE my_file.h5")

# get all directories recursively starting from the root of the file system (/)
HDFql.execute("SHOW DIRECTORY / LIKE **")

# iterate result set and create group in each iteration
while HDFql.cursor_next() == HDFql.SUCCESS:
   HDFql.execute("CREATE GROUP \"%s\"" % HDFql.cursor_get_char())
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to run it but comes up with the error 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'HDFql' any ideas how I can solve this

Comment: You'll need to download HDFql from https://www.hdfql.com/#download and install it in your machine.